# Android X86 6.0 boot stuck on Boot Logo in VMWare

Tags: android-x86, vmware

Today I downloaded the ISO file for the latest Android X86 (64-bit)version - the stable build for Android 6.0 AKA Marhmallow - from https://osdn.jp/projects/android-x86/downloads/65890/android-x86_64-6.0-r1. I have installed this on a virtual machine with **2 processor cores**, **4 GB RAM** and **20 GB Storage** which I think is more than sufficient for this specific OS.

Earlier I was having this problem where the system would boot into `CLI` and not `GUI` hence I googled a bit and followed the instructions from http://techanji.blogspot.in/2013/04/android-wont-boot-into-gui-only-command.html which worked perfectly fine and now I have proper Android boot logo but I kept my system to boot for 15 minutes without any progress which makes me think this has stuck at boot!

**A bit about setup:**

- I did **not** choose GPT for partioning
- I have made one **primary partition** of 20 GB and made it boot partition
- I have formatted my partition with **ext4** file system
- I **installed GRUB** but **not EFI GRUB**

Hopefully, these details are enough and you guys can help me with this.

**PS: For those members who are in a hurry to mark a question as duplicate by just reading the question, I would like to kindly bring it to your notice that I have read and tried ALL the solutions to similar questions and none of them has worked so far, hence posting  this question**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first I had the same issue. But I changed the Display settings and now it works.

- Go to the VM settings's
- Go to Display settings
- Check the Accelerate 3D graphics
- Set the graphics memory to 1GB (if possible)
- Start your VM!