# What is the difference between my Android 7 x86 Live CD, and actual installation? (Stuck on Boot Logo after installing)

Tags: installation, boot, 7.0-nougat, android-x86

I am trying to install Android from the [Android-x86 project](http://www.android-x86.org) on my PC.  I successfully built an ISO from source, and I can boot from it.  The Live CD comes up without any issues.  My problem only shows up after installing Android on my computer.

Grub comes up, allows me to select Android, and starts the android boot process, but then I get stuck on the "android" logo animation screen.

I used `GPT` for partitioning, made one primary partition, and formatted it with `ext4`.

My problems sound very similar to [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/157741/android-x86-6-0-boot-stuck-on-boot-logo-in-vmware), but the OP is in a Virtual Machine.  Is there some way that I need to "Accelerate 3D Graphics" or something like that?

It seems especially bizarre to me that it is booting successfully from the "live" system, but stops working when I install it...

---

**Edit:**

Looking into this some more, I found a workaround.  If I use `ntfs` or `exfat` instead of `ext4` when formatting the partition, it works.  There is a catch: it becomes a read-only filesystem.  The x86 installer helps you set up another space for user data, so this just might be usable...  I am still open for answers on why `ext4` will not boot though.

Comment: Ah, welcome to the broken world of Android-x86! You need to modify some kernel options to make this work. Not sure exactly which ones you need for your machine. The other option is to check for an alternative x86 version of Android, like Remix OS. _Note: I am not affiliated in any way with Remix._

Comment: @MarkYisri I actually made some headway on this (see edit), but I don't know about the kernel options...

Answer (score 0):

try installing the newest Ubuntu fresh. then install android x86 over the ext4 partition. select yes on grub and uefi and read write. do not format anything! ANDROID X86 formatter is broken.